# Where can I find broadband seismic reflection data?

Tags: geology, seismology, seismic

or what type of companies should I contact to ask for the data?

This data would be produced from Seismic Vibroseis survey trucks which are mostly used to locate oil and gas.

I doubt most oil and gas companies would be willing to share the data, even with researchers, so I'm stuck.

Any ideas on how to obtain the digitized response data from several locations?

[image]

Comment: Try asking the oil & gas exploration companies. Some might have data for areas that are no longer relevant to them, or that won't affect their stock price. Be mindful of what you ask for & how you ask for it. Some companies can be very helpful.

Comment: I agree , when I was a member of SPE ,I would see various published papers on seismic  data ( which I don't understand) in the monthly magazine.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what purpose you need the data for.

This site https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Open_data gives several sources of data. If it must be land acquisition (as opposed to marine) data then the Poland 2D, Teapot dome 3D, or Stratton 3D surveys might be of interest.

These free data sets are for pedagogical/research purposes, so if you'd like to 'strike-it-rich' these are not the droids you're looking for.

Hope this helps, 
-D